# Angular-oauth2-oidc clear localStorage expired token info

Tags: angular, typescript, openid-connect, pkce

I'm trying to customise the PKCE flow in angular-oauth2-oidc library for one angular FE project.

I'm also using localStorage for this library to store token and etc info, but I can't seem to find a way how to make it clear expired token info from localStorage.

Shouldn't this be done automatically?